# Why does SQL Server skip over an IF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run the following query:

```
IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar),2) LIKE '1[2-9]'
SELECT
    @@servername AS [Server]
    , d.name AS [Database]
    , CONVERT(char(10), d.create_date, 121) AS [Created]
    , sp.name AS [Owner]
    , d.recovery_model_desc AS [Recovery]
    , CASE d.state_desc                 WHEN 'OFFLINE' THEN '***OFFLINE***' ELSE d.state_desc END AS [Status]
    , d.user_access_desc AS [Access]
    , CASE d.is_read_only               WHEN 0 THEN 'READ_WRITE' WHEN 1 THEN 'READ_ONLY' END AS Updateability
    , CASE d.is_fulltext_enabled        WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [FullText]
    , CASE d.is_auto_create_stats_on    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [CreateStats]
    , CASE d.is_auto_update_stats_on    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [UpdateStats]
    , CASE d.page_verify_option
        WHEN 0 THEN '***NONE***'
        WHEN 1 THEN '***TORN PAGE DETECTION***' -- outdated in 2005+. Change to checksum.
        ELSE d.page_verify_option_desc
    END AS [Page Verify]
    , d.compatibility_level AS [Level]
    , d.target_recovery_time_in_seconds as ckp_s
    , d.log_reuse_wait_desc AS [Log Wait]
    , d.collation_name AS [Collation]
    , CASE d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on  WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [RCS]
    , CASE d.snapshot_isolation_state   WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [SI]
    , CASE d.is_query_store_on WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS QS
    , CASE d.is_auto_close_on           WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN '***YES***' /*always disable auto close*/ END AS [AutoClose]
    , CASE d.is_auto_shrink_on          WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN '***YES***' /*always disable auto shrink*/ END AS [AutoShrink]
    , d.delayed_durability_desc as [Durability]
FROM sys.databases AS d
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp /*get database owner name */ ON sp.sid = d.owner_sid
WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- exclude system DBs
ORDER BY d.name; 
ELSE
SELECT
    @@servername AS [Server]    
    , d.name AS [Database]
    , CONVERT(char(10), d.create_date, 121) AS [Created]
    , sp.name AS [Owner]
    , d.recovery_model_desc AS [Recovery]
    , CASE d.state_desc                 WHEN 'OFFLINE' THEN '***OFFLINE***' ELSE d.state_desc END AS [Status]
    , d.user_access_desc AS [Access]
    , CASE d.is_read_only               WHEN 0 THEN 'READ_WRITE' WHEN 1 THEN 'READ_ONLY' END AS Updateability
    , CASE d.is_fulltext_enabled        WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [FullText]
    , CASE d.is_auto_create_stats_on    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [CreateStats]
    , CASE d.is_auto_update_stats_on    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [UpdateStats]
    , CASE d.page_verify_option
        WHEN 0 THEN '***NONE***'
        WHEN 1 THEN '***TORN PAGE DETECTION***' -- outdated in 2005+. Change to checksum.
        ELSE d.page_verify_option_desc
    END AS [Page Verify]
    , d.compatibility_level AS [Level]
    , 'N/A' AS ckp_s
    , d.log_reuse_wait_desc AS [Log Wait]
    , d.collation_name AS [Collation]
    , CASE d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on  WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [RCS]
    , CASE d.snapshot_isolation_state   WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [SI]
    , 'N/A' AS QS
    , CASE d.is_auto_close_on           WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN '***YES***' /*always disable auto close*/ END AS [AutoClose]
    , CASE d.is_auto_shrink_on          WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN '***YES***' /*always disable auto shrink*/ END AS [AutoShrink]
    , 'N/A' AS [Durability]
FROM sys.databases AS d
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp /*get database owner name */ ON sp.sid = d.owner_sid
WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- exclude system DBs
ORDER BY d.name;
```

The issue is with SQL Server 2005/2008/2012. The columns `target_recovery_time_in_seconds, is_query_store_on, and delayed_durability_desc` don't exist in the sys.databases table.

The IF statement at the top finds what version of SQL Server it is. If it's 2014+, run the query with those 3 columns. If not, run the query without those 3 columns. I've used this logic in other queries and it works but in this instance it does not. I get the following errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
>   Invalid column name 'target_recovery_time_in_seconds'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Invalid column name 'is_query_store_on'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Invalid column name 'is_query_store_on'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
>   Invalid column name 'delayed_durability_desc'.`

My question is why doesn't SQL Server read the IF statement? If it did, it would skip the query with 3 columns and run the one without it.

Comment: It doesn't skip the `IF` statement... it only validates it on execution; but before executing, SQL Server is validating your whole query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will try and compile all statements in the batch (unless they reference an entire object that doesn't exist - when compilation will be deferred. Referencing missing columns for an existing object does not cause deferred compilation.).

There is a [trick you can use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i/66755#66755) though to just have one query that will work in all the versions you are targeting and avoid dynamic SQL.

The columns marked by `<--` below will be resolved from `sys.databases` if they exist in there or fall back to the `dummy` derived table failing that.

```
WITH d
     AS (SELECT x.*
         FROM   (SELECT  'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A')
                AS dummy (is_query_store_on, delayed_durability_desc, target_recovery_time_in_seconds)
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT d.collation_name,
                                    d.compatibility_level,
                                    d.create_date,
                                    d.database_id,
                                    delayed_durability_desc, /* <-- resolved from d or dummy */
                                    d.is_auto_close_on,
                                    d.is_auto_create_stats_on,
                                    d.is_auto_shrink_on,
                                    d.is_auto_update_stats_on,
                                    d.is_fulltext_enabled,
                                    is_query_store_on, /* <-- resolved from d or dummy */
                                    d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on,
                                    d.is_read_only,
                                    d.log_reuse_wait_desc,
                                    d.name,
                                    d.owner_sid,
                                    d.page_verify_option,
                                    d.page_verify_option_desc,
                                    d.recovery_model_desc,
                                    d.snapshot_isolation_state,
                                    d.state_desc,
                                    target_recovery_time_in_seconds, /* <-- resolved from d or dummy */
                                    d.user_access_desc
                             FROM   sys.databases AS d) AS x)
SELECT
    @@servername AS [Server]
    , d.name AS [Database]
    , CONVERT(char(10), d.create_date, 121) AS [Created]
    , sp.name AS [Owner]
    , d.recovery_model_desc AS [Recovery]
    , CASE d.state_desc                 WHEN 'OFFLINE' THEN '***OFFLINE***' ELSE d.state_desc END AS [Status]
    , d.user_access_desc AS [Access]
    , CASE d.is_read_only               WHEN 0 THEN 'READ_WRITE' WHEN 1 THEN 'READ_ONLY' END AS Updateability
    , CASE d.is_fulltext_enabled        WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [FullText]
    , CASE d.is_auto_create_stats_on    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [CreateStats]
    , CASE d.is_auto_update_stats_on    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [UpdateStats]
    , CASE d.page_verify_option
        WHEN 0 THEN '***NONE***'
        WHEN 1 THEN '***TORN PAGE DETECTION***' -- outdated in 2005+. Change to checksum.
        ELSE d.page_verify_option_desc
    END AS [Page Verify]
    , d.compatibility_level AS [Level]
    , d.target_recovery_time_in_seconds as ckp_s
    , d.log_reuse_wait_desc AS [Log Wait]
    , d.collation_name AS [Collation]
    , CASE d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on  WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [RCS]
    , CASE d.snapshot_isolation_state   WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' END AS [SI]
    , CASE d.is_query_store_on WHEN 'false' THEN 'NO' WHEN 'true' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'N/A' END AS QS
    , CASE d.is_auto_close_on           WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN '***YES***' /*always disable auto close*/ END AS [AutoClose]
    , CASE d.is_auto_shrink_on          WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN '***YES***' /*always disable auto shrink*/ END AS [AutoShrink]
    , d.delayed_durability_desc as [Durability]
FROM d
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp /*get database owner name */ ON sp.sid = d.owner_sid
WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- exclude system DBs
ORDER BY d.name;
```

Comment: I’m always in for avoiding dynamic sql when possible. Good tip here.

Comment: @MartinSmith, that works perfectly! Thank you for the lesson and the tip!

Answer (score 2):

When a SQL query is executed, the whole thing gets evaluated first. So when you run it on SQL2012 or earlier, the fields don't exist, so your query isn't valid, because those fields don't exist, even if that section wouldn't be executed.

You could try using some dynamic sql to work around this - build the whole command into a string with the various elements you require, and execute it using `sp_executesql`

eg:

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

 select @sql = 'SELECT @@servername AS [Server], d.name AS [Database] '
 -- some fields omitted here for brevity

 IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar),2) LIKE '1[2-9]'
 begin
     select @sql = @sql + ', CASE d.is_query_store_on WHEN 0 THEN ''NO'' WHEN 1 THEN ''YES'' END AS QS '
 end
 else
 begin
    select @sql = @sql + ', ''N/A'' as QS '
 end 
 select @sql = @sql + ' FROM sys.databases AS d LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp /*get database owner name */ ON sp.sid = d.owner_sid WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- exclude system DBs ORDER BY d.name; '

 exec sp_executesql @sql
```